# Changing nested list column in dataframe to dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

My question here is twofold:

I've got a pandas dataframe in which one of the columns is a nested list in the following form:

```
[['linkedin', '...'], ['country', '...'], ['location', 'United Kingdom London London'], ['city', 'London'], ['state', 'London']...]
```

and I want to change every entry in the column to a dictionary so i can actually access the items using the keys:

```
{'linkedin': '...', 'country': 'United Kingdom', 'location': 'United Kingdom London London', 'city': 'London', 'state': 'London'..}
```

While this seems to be perfectly doable by typecasting using dict for single entries I'm having difficulties actually managing to do this for all the column entries. For example, I've tried the following, as well as for loops, but am having difficulties:

```
df['graphResults']=df['graphResults'].astype(dict)
```

,

```
df['graphResults']=dict(df['graphResults'])
```

,

```
for(x in range(0,df.shape[0])):
    df.graphResults[x] = dict(df.graphResults[x])
```

How is this done?

Secondly, after I've achieved this I want to actually take some of the fields and add them as columns in their own right within the dataframe. Is there a straightforward method for this?

Comment: `df['graphResults'].apply(dict)` ? If you want to turn into columns after you can try the following: `df.join(pd.DataFrame.from_records(df['graphResults'].apply(dict).values))`

Comment: @gyx-hh this is the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

moving my comment as an answer. Using apply on `graphResults` to convert to `dict`. From those values you can create a new `DataFrame` and join with the original one.

```
df.join(pd.DataFrame.from_records(df['graphResults'].apply(dict).values))
```

To only select some of the fields you can do the following:

```
df.join(pd.DataFrame.from_records(df['graphResults'].apply(dict).values)[['country', 'location']])
```

The above will only add `location` and `country` fields.

Comment: Thanks, this has been perfect on both fronts!

Comment: I have another question actually now, for some entries the fields in the dictionary aren't always consistent which causes errors during the joining part. giving: KeyError: "['city'] not in index" for example. Is there a way that I can work around this by leaving any cases where this happens as null values rather than the whole process cutting?

Comment: right so sometimes ['city', '...'] is missing from the list ? let me quickly look into that for you.

Comment: this seems to work fine. `pd.DataFrame.from_records(..)` will create a `df` with all keys that exist in `dict` values inside `df['graphResults']`. So you would only get this error if none of the lists inside `graphResults` have 'city'.

Answer (score 0):

Like:

```
l = [['linkedin', '...'], ['country', '...'], ['location', 'United Kingdom London London'], \
     ['city', 'London'], ['state', 'London']]

d = {i[0]:i[1:] for i in l}
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the dictionary part I can do:

```
data = [['linkedin', '...'], ['country', '...'],['location', 'United Kingdom London London'], ['city', 'London'], ['state', 'London']]
new_dict = {}
for combination in data:
    new_dict[combination[0]] = combination[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this:

```
l = [['linkedin', '...'], ['country', '...'], ['location', 'United Kingdom London London'], \
     ['city', 'London'], ['state', 'London']]

dict_df  = {dict_df[0]:dict_df[1:] for dict_df in l}
```